# Uploading Screenshots to Firebase with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to upload the screenshot image to Firestore, but I am having some null errors,

```
Future uploadImagetoFirebase() async {
await screenshotController.capture().then((value) => (File image) {
      _screenshot = image;
    });

String fileName = _screenshot.path;
Reference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('orders/$fileName');
UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_screenshot);
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) => print('Done: $value'));


}
```

I am calling it with button like this:

```
 onPressed: () async {
            await uploadImagetoFirebase(); }
```

This is the error stack:

```
 flutter ( 5143): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5143): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 5143): Tried calling: path
E/flutter ( 5143): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter ( 5143): #1      _CartState.uploadImagetoFirebase
package:CWCFlutter/model/cart.dart:88
E/flutter ( 5143): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5143): #2      _CartState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:CWCFlutter/model/cart.dart:310
E/flutter ( 5143): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:993
E/flutter ( 5143): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:1111
E/flutter ( 5143): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter ( 5143): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
E/flutter ( 5143): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
E/flutter ( 5143): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:222
E/flutter ( 5143): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:476
E/flutter ( 5143): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77
E/flutter ( 5143): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122
E/flutter ( 5143): #12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter ( 5143): #13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120
E/flutter ( 5143): #14     PointerRouter.route
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106
E/flutter ( 5143): #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:358
E/flutter ( 5143): #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:338
E/flutter ( 5143): #17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:267
E/flutter ( 5143): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:295
E/flutter ( 5143): #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:240
E/flutter ( 5143): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:213
E/flutter ( 5143): #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter ( 5143): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 5143): #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter ( 5143): #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter ( 5143): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
```

I am not sure how path was called on null, any ideas? Basically I await for the app to take a screenshot, then add that image in _screenshot File variable, then try to store it in 'orders' folder in Firestore. I have searched for answers, and they say you need to initialize Firestore somewhere, but I am not sure where that would be, I have only worked with older versions, and not sure how to do all things in the newer ones. Thank you!

I have tried setting the state as well, but getting the same error:

```
Future uploadImagetoFirebase() async {
await screenshotController.capture().then((value) => (File image) {
    setState(() {
              _screenshot = image;
          });     
});
```

**What I came up with that seems to work as a solution**

```
    Future<String> uploadImagetoFirebase2() async {
    File img = await screenshotController.capture();
    setState(() {
      _screenshot = img;
    });
//change filename not to be path, but something else short
    String fileName = img.path;

    Reference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('orders/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_screenshot);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = (await uploadTask);
    String uri = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    print(uri);
    return uri;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
Future<String> uploadImagetoFirebase() async {
File img = await screenshotController.capture();

String fileName = img.path;

Reference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('orders/$fileName');
UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_screenshot);
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = (await uploadTask);
String uri = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
print(uri);
return uri;
}
```

Comment: `await uploadTask.onComplete` getting an error here which says onComplete isn't defined for type `UploadTask`, I suppose that is new Firebase syntax.

Comment: I'll try it out today, appreciated! Do I still need to setState after capture? Something like `setState{(_screenshot = img)}`

Comment: Edited the main post with my solution, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> flutter ( 5143): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null.
> E/flutter ( 5143): Receiver: null
> E/flutter ( 5143): Tried calling: path

your path is null,
you can solve this in two ways

**1. setstate**

```
Future uploadImagetoFirebase() async {
await screenshotController.capture().then((value) => (File image) {
    setState(() {
              _screenshot = image;
          });     
});
```

//... your fireabase upload function

**2 return from future**

```
 Future <File> uploadImagetoFirebase() async {
    File myImage=await screenshotController.capture();
    retun myImage
        );
    //get image onPress btn
    
     onPressed: () async {
              var myFile=  await uploadImagetoFirebase();
//check if path is null  using if ...
print(myFile.path);
    // firebase function
Reference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('orders/${myFile.path}');
UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(myFile);
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = (await uploadTask);
String uri = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
print(uri);
return uri;
     }
```

Comment: I have tried setting the state, but for some reason got the same error, I'll try out your second fix, but not sure how it would work in my context here, any chance you could add some code to your second example?

Comment: i have updated my answer..try printing the logs

Comment: Will do, appreciate it!

Comment: Edited the main post with my solution thanks to you guys.